# Create A Variable for Struct (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, variables, struct

I have two structs which look like this:

```
struct Song {
    var title: String
    var artist: String
}

var songs: [Song] = [
    Song(title: "Title 1", artist: "Artist 1"),
    Song(title: "Title 2", artist: "Artist 2"),
}
```

and

```
struct Song2 {
        var title: String
        var artist: String
    }

    var songs2: [Song] = [
        Song(title: "Title 1", artist: "Artist 1"),
        Song(title: "Title 2", artist: "Artist 2"),
    }
```

I want to create a variable that changes so on diffrent events either the first struct will be referenced, or the second struct will be referenced. Like this.

```
var structToBeReferenced = //What goes here?
```

**ViewController1**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

structToBeReferenced = songs
}
```

**ViewController2**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

    structToBeReferenced = songs2
    }
```

**ViewController3**

```
func theFunction() {
label.text = structToBeReferenced[thisSong].title
}
```

Basically, I just want to create a variable that can be changed so that in **ViewController1**, it sets `structToBeReferenced` to `songs`. **ViewController2** sets `structToBeReferenced` to `songs2`. So that in **ViewController3** whenever `theFunction()` is called, the right library is referenced.

I hope that made sense. I just need to know what the variable, `structToBeReferenced`, needs to equal. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not really sure what are you trying to achieve. What's the purpose of declaring two completely unrelated, though identical in implementation, structs?

Comment: @mag_zbc I have 2 song libraries. Both display on a `UITableView`. When a user clicks on the cell, it opens a player view. Both tableviews open the same player view. I need this so that the right song library will be referenced in the player view.

Comment: @JacobCavin, well, then you need two collections, not two different, but similar types.

Answer (score 2):

Create a [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID267) that both structs conform to. Something like this:

```
protocol SongProtocol {
    var title: String { get set }
}
```

Then your structs would conform to the protocol like this:

```
struct Song: SongProtocol {
    var title: String
    var artist: String
}
```

Now in your view controllers you can declare the struct property using the protocol type:

```
var structToBeReferenced: SongProtocol = // your struct here
```

This way, both struct types are guaranteed to have the title property but you can use which ever one you need to so long as they conform to the `SongProtocol`.